# JSTree empties ul while initiliazing a tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jstree

We want to switch to JSTree from Kendo Treeview
I have got a tree prepared as HTML Datasource like this:

```
<div id="ablesaa00" style="display:none"><ul id="a00"><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/strasse_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">Am Sillerkamp<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">1<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Brockmann,<ul><li id="a1" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a2" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Brockmann,Stephan<ul><li id="a3" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">3<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Kollakowsky,Estella &amp; Thomas<ul><li id="a4" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Kollakowsky,Estella &amp; Thomas<ul><li id="a5" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">5<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Schammler,Horst<ul><li id="a6" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Schammler,Horst<ul><li id="a7" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Schammler,Guido<ul><li id="a8" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">6<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Schniggendiller,Dirk<ul><li id="a9" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a10" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Schniggendiller,Dirk<ul><li id="a11" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">7<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Altenknecht,Josef<ul><li id="a12" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Altenknecht,Josef<ul><li id="a13" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">7A<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Altenknecht,Susanne<ul><li id="a14" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">8<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Springeneer,Markus<ul><li id="a15" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a16" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Springeneer,Markus<ul><li id="a17" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">9<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Fortmann,Mayk u. Sandra<ul><li id="a18" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a19" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Fortmann,Mayk u. Sandra<ul><li id="a20" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Beckmann,Walter<ul><li id="a21" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a22" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">11<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Klaas,Herbert/Rita<ul><li id="a23" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Klaas,Herbert/Rita<ul><li id="a24" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">12<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Griese,Bernhard<ul><li id="a25" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Griese,Bernhard<ul><li id="a26" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a27" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">14<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Griese,Christoph<ul><li id="a28" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Griese,Christoph<ul><li id="a29" farbe="0">G</li><li id="a30" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">15<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Wautmann,Mathilde<ul><li id="a31" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a32" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Wautmann,Mathilde<ul><li id="a33" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">16<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> van der Burg,Rudolf<ul><li id="a34" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a35" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> van der Burg,Rudolf<ul><li id="a36" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">17<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Schenk,Karl/Renate<ul><li id="a37" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Mückenheim,Christine u. Bernd<ul><li id="a38" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a39" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">19<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Schenk,Karl/Renate<ul><li id="a40" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Schwarzmeier,Hans Werner<ul><li id="a41" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Schwarzmeier<ul><li id="a42" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">20<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Karns,Bernd<ul><li id="a44" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Karns,Bernd<ul><li id="a45" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Karns,Mike<ul><li id="a47" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">21<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Gerle,Joachim/Angela<ul><li id="a48" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a49" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Gerle,Joachim/Angela<ul><li id="a50" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">23<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Bresser,Bernhard<ul><li id="a51" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a52" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Bresser,Bernhard<ul><li id="a53" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Burghoff,Stefan<ul><li id="a54" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a55" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">24<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Marczewski,Birgit/Guido<ul><li id="a56" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a57" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Marczewski,Birgit/Guido<ul><li id="a58" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">25<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Jasper,Martin<ul><li id="a59" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Jasper,Martin<ul><li id="a60" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a61" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">27<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Bergknecht,Birgit u. Andreas<ul><li id="a62" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Bergknecht,Birgit u. Andreas<ul><li id="a63" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">28<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Schlattmann,Jochen<ul><li id="a64" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Bendiek,Thomas<ul><li id="a65" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Bendiek,Thomas<ul><li id="a66" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">29<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Schlichting,Monika<ul><li id="a67" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Schlichting,Monika<ul><li id="a68" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Elspass,Nadine und Mike<ul><li id="a69" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">31<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Struffert,Ulrike<ul><li id="a70" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Struffert,Ulrike<ul><li id="a71" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Gramsch,Simone<ul><li id="a72" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">33<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Rolke,Uwe<ul><li id="a73" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Rolke,Uwe<ul><li id="a74" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a75" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">36<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Pieper,Theodor/Maria<ul><li id="a76" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Pieper,Theodor/Maria<ul><li id="a77" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Petrovic,Ilinka<ul><li id="a78" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">39<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Schützenhafer,Marion<ul><li id="a79" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a80" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Schützehofer,Marion<ul><li id="a81" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">40<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Klaas,Martin/Ursula<ul><li id="a82" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a83" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Klaas,Martin/Ursula<ul><li id="a84" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">41<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Bernemann,Karl<ul><li id="a85" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a86" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Bernemann,Karl<ul><li id="a87" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">42<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Werner,Helga<ul><li id="a88" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Werner,Helga<ul><li id="a89" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a90" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">43<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Strotmann,Ludger<ul><li id="a91" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Strotmann,Ludger<ul><li id="a92" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a93" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">44<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Jaszczerski,Sabine/Frank<ul><li id="a94" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a95" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Jaszczerski,Sabine/Frank<ul><li id="a96" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">45<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Strotmann,Frank/Anja<ul><li id="a97" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a98" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Strotmann,Frank/Anja<ul><li id="a99" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">46<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Lindemann,Bernhard/Roswitha<ul><li id="a100" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a101" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Lindemann,Bernhard/Roswitha<ul><li id="a102" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">47<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Rogowski,Reinhard<ul><li id="a103" farbe="0">G</li><li id="a104" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Rogowski,Reinhard<ul><li id="a105" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">48<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Grieger,Werner<ul><li id="a106" farbe="0">G</li><li id="a107" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Grieger,Werner<ul><li id="a108" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">49<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Petzel,Margret<ul><li id="a109" farbe="0">W</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Petzel,Margret<ul><li id="a110" farbe="0">S</li><li id="a111" farbe="0">G</li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Langer,Nicole<ul><li id="a112" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li></ul></li><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/haus_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;">60<ul><li farbe="0"><img src="styles/images/person_rot.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> Hullermann,Ludwig<ul><li id="a113" farbe="0">S</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></div>
```

Then we run the command to initiliaze the tree with JSTree but then we get an empty ul back like this:

```
<div id="ablesaa00" style="display:block;"><ul id="a00" class="jstree jstree-3 jstree-default jstree-leaf" role="tree"><ul class="jstree-container-ul jstree-children"></ul></ul></div>
```

This is just an empty tree.
We are not sure why this happens since we also do not get any js errors.
I hope you can help us

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to provide your data for the tree in a JSON format for JSTree to generate its own nodes

Comment: It is possible to provide the data also in html as datasource like mentioned here: http://www.jstree.com/docs/html/ Or do I get something wrong there?

Comment: I tested the example. It works. It just does not work the data we provide but why?

Comment: Cool if they say HTML is fine too, it's been a while since I've used JSTree. I do know that their documentation is not always as helpful as you might expect. If your ul is empty it probably means JSTree failed to parse your HTML structure. Have you checked the console etc for errors?

Comment: Yes I checked the console but nothing shows up there

Comment: It could be something like your HTML not being valid, for example what is the `farbe` attribute you're putting on your `li` elements? jQuery often produces inconsistent results with invalid HTML markup, so a good rule of thumb is not to make up your own attributes. Use data attributes for custom information, classes for common links and IDs for unique identifiers

Comment: Oh ok I will directly check that

Comment: Ok it seems like I am not initiliazing on the correct div or something. I just tested it manualy by putting the prepared div into the code and starting the initialization. it works so far that I get the root node. No subnodes but a beginning

Comment: I noticed the following. It now works if I run this on my desktop pc but if I run this command inside the app on Android it does only add the root node